# Reference FSharp.Data within online repls

Tags: f#, f#-data

I wonder if and how I could make use of packages like `FSharp.Data` at online REPLs such as [repl.it](https://repl.it). The usual `#r` or `#load` are not sufficient, maybe I'm lacking knowledge on how these environments work.

So does anybody know how to enable them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot say anything about [repl.it](https://repl.it/), but in [Azure Notebooks](https://notebooks.azure.com) `Paket` is supported. Below is a screenshot of a quick demo I've crafted for you demonstrating pull of `FSharp.Data` into your REPL:

[image: F# Notebook with FSharp.Data]

All magic happens in the first cell:

- `#load "Paket.fsx"` enables [paket](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/index.html) within jupyter environment
- the following expression `Paket.Dependencies.Install [dependencies list]` specifies external dependencies for the notebook and their source(s), just like `paket.dependencies` file in F# paket build environment
- the following expression `Paket.Package [libraries list]` generates references to downloaded libraries as `#r <path>` directives bound to the local notebook environment
- finally, `#load Paket.Generated.Refs.fsx` performs the actual referencing.

The cells following one with the `paket` machinery may customarily `open` library namespaces and use the associated library entities.

Comment: Seems like a nice alternative! Although still wondering about the other repls and their options.

Comment: I got "input.fsx (2,1)-(2,18) interactive error Unable to find the file 'Paket.fsx' in any of .. ". How to fix this?